# Tailwind CSS responsive breakpoint not working on text-center and text-left

Tags: responsive, tailwind-css

hi i am new in learning tailwind css.
my line of code is

```html
<h1 className="text-center sm:text-left">Hello world</h1>
```

This means "hello world" should be at center on mobile breakpont and it should go left on sm or heigher break points. But "Hello world" remains at the center at all break points why?
am i missing somthing? and thanks for the help.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://play.tailwindcss.com/jIeyHfzKco But what mike wrote maybe the cause in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine here, see

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<h1 class="text-center sm:text-left">Hello world</h1>
```

Notice two things,

- See whether other classes like `bg-red-400` or `text-blue-800` is working or not. If not , then tailwind is not working properly.
- See if you are using any JS framework( React, Next, Nuxt) then `className` is fine, but if you are using pure HTML, then replace it with `class` only.

Answer (score -1):

I am mentioning this, purely because I have had it happening to me sometime in the past.

You are using `className` as an attibute on your HTML, now you could be using react or some other framework, but if this is vanilla HTML, you can't do that, and have to use `class` instead.

Please use the following instead:

```
<h1 class="text-center sm:text-left">Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer might be a little late but you probably misunderstood how the breakpoints work with Tailwind (It confused me too when I started with Tailwind).
Basically  when you set a style with a breakpoint like:

```
<h1 className="text-center sm:text-left">Hello world</h1>
```

What's happening is that from the md breakpoint **upwards**, everything will be text-left. So on md, lg, xl, etc, it will have text-left.